# Is there anyway to assign a default position for the circular button in an ionic range slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic slider, in which I get the value from and assign another scope variable:

`<input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="100" step="25" name="lineProgress" ng-model="progress" ng-change=lineProgress(progress)>`

When the value of progress changes, it assigns certain text to another $scope variable that is shown under it.

Without sliding the button, however, its default position seems to be in the middle[image]

The $scope variable is not assigned at this point, but I would like the button to be all the way to the left.  I thought by assigning, value = 0, it would do that. Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try assigning value to $scope.progess=0 and remove value filed from input.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" name="lineProgress" ng-model="progress" ng-change=lineProgress(progress)>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.progress="0";
```

may be this could help you.it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `ng-init` in your HTML to set `progress` to `0` (i.e. `ng-init="progress = 0"`). It should accomplish the same thing.